# Im having an error when adding a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECIMAL(3, 2)' at line 1

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    stud_id INT,
    name_f VARCHAR(20),
    email  VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(stud_id)
);

DESCRIBE student;

DROP TABLE student;

ALTER TABLE student ADD DECIMAL(3, 2);
```

my full code is those.

Comment: Weirdly you cannot alter a table you have dropped..

Comment: `ALTER TABLE student ADD DECIMAL(3, 2);` is missing a column name

Comment: Hint:  `ALTER TABEL ADD student DECIMAL(3, 2)`.

Comment: If you dropped a table, it not longer exists. How can you do further operation (e.g.alter table ?)

Comment: @P.Salmon I deleted the line on drop syntax but still did'nt work

Comment: There are 2 errors see answer from @gmb Your ide stops at the first error it sees not necessarily the first error in the code block.

Comment: You had 2 problems. Eliminating one of them is not enough.

Comment: What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: @Riza Marcos did you read the answer from @GMB? If you don't agree with it please comment in the answer.

Comment: @P.Salmon It already works. I didn't notice his answer a while ago. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dropping the table before trying to add the new column. Also, you need to give the new column a name.

This makes more sense:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    stud_id INT,
    name_f VARCHAR(20),
    email  VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(stud_id)
);

ALTER TABLE student ADD newcol DECIMAL(3, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

DROP TABLE student; drops the table from the db so you can't manipulate it again.

Also, your alter statement does not include the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You have dropped the table using the **DROP TABLE student.**..
Therefore you can not do anything to it since it's deleted after dropping it